# How to add single quotes across a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I am iterating over a config.yml from from which parsing the values in a string form as follows:

```
machines:  
 A:
  ip: 10.11.12
  pass: vass
B:
  ip: 10.11.13
  pass: grass
```

The above config.yml is parsed as follows:

```
machines = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
var=''
machines[A].each do |letters,hash|
   var += "[" + hash['ip'] + "]\n" + hash['pass'] + "\n"
end
```

The "var" value i am getting as :

```
   "[10.11.12]\nvass\n[10.11.13]\ngrass\n"
```

but instead like above i dont want double quotes rather single quotes across complete atring as follows:

```
   '[10.11.12]\nvass\n[10.11.13]\ngrass\n'
```

So, please suggest how can have single quotes across the string.

Comment: In Ruby, every string is shown as a double quoted sequence of characters. The single quote (') is to **construct** a string with every character interpreted as literal. `x = 'Hello\nWorld' #=> "Hello\\nWorld"`. What you intended to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the `puts` will print the value of the string without double quotes in the console.

So may be you can use `puts var` so that double quotes are not getting printed. And now you can wrap your content with single quote using string interpolation.

`var += "'#{actual_value}'"`